# Bars are showing up even when value is zero - Google Charts

Tags: mysql, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have created a monthly chart using Google charts but the bars are showing up even when the value is zero.

Here is the screenshot of it

[image: Monthly Sale Chart]

and here is the code and I know code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You can ignore it. This is only for testing purpose

Previously order_total_amount column was set to "VARCHAR" datatype, then someone suggested that it should set to the "INT". So I changed it from Varchar to Int. But that didn't solved the problem. Bar is still showing up despite having 0 value

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Monthly', 'Sales'],
          <?php   
            
    $sale_chart = "SELECT 
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
    SUM(IF(month = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'May',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'
    FROM
    (SELECT 
        MIN(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b')) AS month,
            SUM(order_total_amount) AS total
    FROM
        invoice_order
    WHERE
        user_id = '$user_id'
    GROUP BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)) AS sale";

$sale_chart_query = mysqli_query($connection,$sale_chart) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$sale_chart_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sale_chart_query);
            
          foreach($sale_chart_array as $x => $val) { ?>
          ['<?php echo $x; ?>','<?php echo $val; ?>'],
           <?php } ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
        
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
     </script>
```

After replacing zero with null, that is how it showing up the result

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try using `null` instead of zero

Comment: I set the default to null in PHPMyAdmin. but that too didn't solve the problem or are you asking me to do changes in query? @WhiteHat

Comment: Are you asking me to do this  "SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, null))  AS 'Jan'"? relacing zero with null in a query?

Comment: I just tried it. I added the screenshot of the result at the end of the question. Could you please check it? @WhiteHat

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the axis is not starting from zero now and neither zero value showing up in months

Comment: the value in the chart's data table should be `null`

Comment: Already tried it but unfortunately, it didn't work. Bars are still showing up @WhiteHat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a value of `null` in the chart's data table will prevent a bar from appearing.
see following working snippet...

in this case, you're including strings instead of numbers in the data table.
remove the single quotes from the second array value, here...

```
['<?php echo $x; ?>',<?php echo $val; ?>],
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Monthly', 'Sales'],
    ['Jan', 1000],
    ['Feb', null],
    ['Mar', null],
    ['Apr', null],
    ['May', 40000],
    ['Jun', null],
    ['Jul', null],
    ['Aug', null],
    ['Sep', null],
    ['Oct', null],
    ['Nov', null],
    ['Dec', null]
  ]);

  var options = {};

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly. Single quotes were the culprit here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just one quick question! Is it possible to make the chart appear if there are no values? Because chart completely disappear if there are no values @WhiteHat

Comment: you have to provide data to draw a chart, even if all the values are null. as such, use an if statement to determine if the data table has rows, if not, add some blank ones.

Comment: Got it! Thank you